# os.path.idsir() return different result for absolute path and path created with os.path.join() method

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
>>> os.getcwd()
'/Users/seungjunlee/test_dir'
>>> p1 = os.path.abspath('sub_1')
>>> p2 = os.path.join('test_dir', 'sub_1')
>>> os.path.isdir(p1)
True
>>> os.path.isdir(p2)
False
```

So the current working directory is `test_dir`, and there is sub directory called `sub_1`. p1 stores absolute path of sub_1 and p2 get path using join method of path module.

But thing is `os.path.isdir(p1)` and `os.path.isdir(p2)` yield different result. How is this possible, what U'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already under the directory of `test_dir`, and `os.path.join('test_dir', 'sub_1')` returns `test_dir\\sub_1`.

So, in fact what you are checking is `/Users/seungjunlee/test_dir/test_dir/sub_1`, surely it's not valid dir.